# New SQL Install already has me locked out for root

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going a bit bonkers over this but this is what is happening.

I am installing mysql and mysql server but running the mysql_secure_installation and it already has me locked out of root.

Here's the full deal of what I went through. I have no idea what the password default may be but everyone keeps saying try "root" or just pressing enter (no password at all). How on earth am I locked out from the get go?

```
    [root@Gretchen ~]# dnf install mysql mysql-server
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:52:35 ago on Tue Jan  5 10:07:03 2016.
Dependencies resolved.
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                       Arch                                          Version                                                          Repository                                                Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mecab                                                         x86_64                                        0.996-1.fc23.3                                                   fedora                                                   393 k
 mecab-ipadic                                                  x86_64                                        2.7.0.20070801-11.fc23.1                                         fedora                                                    11 M
 mysql-community-client                                        x86_64                                        5.7.10-1.fc23                                                    mysql57-community                                         25 M
 mysql-community-common                                        x86_64                                        5.7.10-1.fc23                                                    mysql57-community                                        274 k
 mysql-community-libs                                          x86_64                                        5.7.10-1.fc23                                                    mysql57-community                                        2.2 M
 mysql-community-server                                        x86_64                                        5.7.10-1.fc23                                                    mysql57-community                                        105 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  6 Packages

Total download size: 143 M
Installed size: 670 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/6): mysql-community-common-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                       629 kB/s | 274 kB     00:00
(2/6): mysql-community-libs-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                         609 kB/s | 2.2 MB     00:03
(3/6): mecab-0.996-1.fc23.3.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                       588 kB/s | 393 kB     00:00
(4/6): mecab-ipadic-2.7.0.20070801-11.fc23.1.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                      662 kB/s |  11 MB     00:16
(5/6): mysql-community-client-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                       1.0 MB/s |  25 MB     00:23
(6/6): mysql-community-server-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                       1.9 MB/s | 105 MB     00:55
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                                                        2.5 MB/s | 143 MB     00:56
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Installing  : mecab-0.996-1.fc23.3.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                              1/6
  Installing  : mysql-community-common-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                              2/6
  Installing  : mysql-community-libs-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                3/6
  Installing  : mysql-community-client-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                              4/6
  Installing  : mecab-ipadic-2.7.0.20070801-11.fc23.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                             5/6
  Installing  : mysql-community-server-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                              6/6
  Verifying   : mysql-community-client-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                              1/6
  Verifying   : mysql-community-libs-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                2/6
  Verifying   : mysql-community-common-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                              3/6
  Verifying   : mysql-community-server-5.7.10-1.fc23.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                              4/6
  Verifying   : mecab-0.996-1.fc23.3.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                              5/6
  Verifying   : mecab-ipadic-2.7.0.20070801-11.fc23.1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                             6/6

Installed:
  mecab.x86_64 0.996-1.fc23.3                    mecab-ipadic.x86_64 2.7.0.20070801-11.fc23.1    mysql-community-client.x86_64 5.7.10-1.fc23    mysql-community-common.x86_64 5.7.10-1.fc23    mysql-community-libs.x86_64 5.7.10-1.fc23
  mysql-community-server.x86_64 5.7.10-1.fc23

Complete!
[root@Gretchen ~]#
[root@Gretchen ~]# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
[root@Gretchen ~]#
[root@Gretchen ~]#
[root@Gretchen ~]# cd /usr/bin
[root@Gretchen bin]# mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[root@Gretchen bin]# mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[root@Gretchen bin]#
```

of course if I uninstall and re-install this continues to happen. I'm afraid I may have installed something else that I should be uninstalling also but I'm unsure.

I have no interest in keeping any databases or users or anything. I just want to have SQL starting from scratch without having to redo my entire server.

Comment: Try re-installing and using the mysql client to connect `mysql -u root` or `mysql -u root -p` the password should just be just pressing enter. Once in change the root password and try the secure install again. just a thought

Comment: Also before you un-install check the config file for `datadir` and completely remove it. The data directory might be `/var/lib/mysql `

Answer (score 0):

Typically mysql stores your initial root password would be stored in `/root/.mysql_secret`. Check it out.

Comment: Hm... I don't see it in /root/ or can locate a .mysql_secret file anywhere. /root
[root@Gretchen ~]# ls -la .mysql_secret
ls: cannot access .mysql_secret: No such file or directory

Comment: got it ... so not sure when this happens but ... apparently a temporary password is made when you first do it (crazy!) its in /var/log/mysqld.log

Answer (score 0):

You may have to start the service with:

```
service mysql start
```

Then try `mysql_secure_installation` again.